# JSON: Serialize a dictionary with complex object in key

Tags: json

What is the best way to serialize a dictionary when `key` is a complex type. For example consider this **invalid** `json`:

```
[
   {ParentId:1, ParentName:'X'}:
        [{'ChildId':'1', 'ChildName':'a'}, {'ChildId':'2', 'ChildName':'b'}],

   {ParentId:2, ParentName:'Y'}:
        [{'ChildId':"3", 'ChildName':'c'}]}
]
```

Is there any way to correctly serialize this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not a valid json, so the answer would be no :-( keys have to be strings. You could reorganize your data structure to wrap your children list into a "parent" object which has an id and a name !

Basically it would look like :

```
[
    {
        "ParentId": 1,
        "ParentName": "X",
        "children": [
            {
                "ChildId": 1,
                "ChildName": "a"
            },
            {
                "ChildId": 2,
                "ChildName": "b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ParentId": 2,
        "ParentName": "Y",
        "children": [
            {
                "ChildId": 3,
                "ChildName": "c"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You can find the specifications of JSON here : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the json with keys as strings and values as your complex object.

In addition, your keys of the complex type should be strings as well.

For example:

```
[
  {
    "name": {
      "ParentId": 1,
      "ParentName": "X"
    },
    "value": [
      {
        "ChildId": "1",
        "ChildName": "a"
      },
      {
        "ChildId": "2",
        "ChildName": "b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "ParentId": 2,
      "ParentName": "Y"
    },
    "value": [
      {
        "ChildId": "3",
        "ChildName": "c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```